# Ajax update panel working very slowly

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have an Ajax comboBox with a list of contacts called comboContacts with an option of "Create new contact". If an existing contact is selected the phone numbers and email of the contact are retreived from the data base and the phone numbers are inserted into another Ajax comboBox and the email is inserted into a textBox. If "Create new contact" is selected a small registry form is opened on the page with text boxes and save and cancel buttons. The phone combo and the email textBox and the new contact form are each in a seperate update panel and the trigger for each of them is the SelectedIndexChanged event of the comboContacts comboBox. If "Create new contact" is selected it takes a very long time to react and if an existing contact is selected it also takes a long time to react if at all. Is there a problem with having a number of updatePanels reacting to the same event? Is there a better and simple alternative to the Ajax updaePanel wthout or using a minimum of JavaScript?

Comment: Before I added the update panels there were no problems, this seems to indicate that the problem is not there.

Comment: Update Panels are notorious for this behavior.  I would just use javascript.

Comment: @ TheGeekYouNeed I prefer to use as little javascript as possible, can you suggest how?